# C++ returning a vector/map of pointers from a public member function

Tags: c++

I have a quick question on the implications of returning a pointer to a vector or map of pointers from a public member function in a class.

Here is my code:

here is a member function in class B

```
vector<A*>* ClassB::getfunction(){
    returns m_test;
}
```

m_test is a private data member of class B of type pointer to a vector of pointers. This object would be initialized on the heap so I would need to delete it in the class destructor (including all the elements in the vector).

I would then use the function as shown below.

```
B* ex_B = new B();

vector<A*>* ex_ptr_vecA = new vector<A*>;  

ex_ptr_vecA = ex_B->getfunction();
```

My question:

Since I have two objects that's memory is both allocated on the heap will I need to delete them both?

Does the order matter and would the following be correct?

```
B* ex_B = new B();

vector<A*>* ex_ptr_vecA = new vector<A*>;  

ex_ptr_vecA = ex_B->getfunction();

//do something with ex_ptr_vecA
//Then I want to delete the allocate memory to the heap

//delete class B first
delete ex_B;

//and then the vector
//need to loop over vector elements and delete one at a time
for(int i =0; i < ex_ptr_vecA; i++){
     delete ex_ptr_vecA->at(i);
}

delete ex_ptr_vecA;
```

Would this be correct or would I be trying to delete dangling pointers because the destructor of class B has already de-allocated the heap memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
B* ex_B = new B();
vector<A*>* ex_ptr_vecA = new vector<A*>;
```

Here you allocated 2 blocks of memory and stored the adress of the beginning of those blocks in corresponding pointer variables. All fine.

```
ex_ptr_vecA = ex_B->getfunction();
```

Now you've reassigned ex_ptr_vecA with whatever address `getfunction()` returns. You no longer hold the address that new `vector<A*>` returned, you can't free it anymore, hence you've got a memory leak.

If you only need the pointer to `ex_B`'s internal `vector<A*>` then simply say this:

```
vector<A*>* ex_ptr_vecA = ex_B->getfunction();
```

The way you showed in your example code `ex_ptr_vecA` points to the same vector that you've allocated in `ex_B` class. If `ex_B` deletes that internal vector in it's destructor, then `delete ex_ptr_vecA;` means you're deleting twice - that's undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

While I don't think the line

```
ex_ptr_vecA = ex_B->getfunction();
```

compiles (you assign "vector of pointers" => "pointer to vector of pointers"), you'll need only two deletes. B owns the pointer returned in ex_ptr_vecA, so it and only it is responsible for its destruction. Your code corrected:

```
B::B() : m_test( new vector<A*>() ) {}
B::~B() { delete m_test; }

B* ex_B = new B();
vector<A*>* ex_ptr_vecA;
ex_ptr_vecA = ex_B->getfunction();
// Do something
delete ex_B;
```

You see, the point about this code is that every new has a delete at the same level of code to ease thinking about allocation and deallocation. To simplify this further, read up about RAII.

Comment: Ah sorry Typo. in the function should return a pointer to a vector of pointers. Would this still give me the same result?

Comment: @MWright: Yes, it would. If m_test belongs to B (read: is a member of B), only B should delete it. You can use scoped_ptr and references to make this clear.

Comment: does that mean I only need to delete ex_B? Could you show me a solution to the above code?

Comment: What if vector<A*>* ex_ptr_vecA = new vector<A*>; before assigning it to the object from class B? Would I just add a delete ex_ptr_vecA. This is where my confusion begins as I am not sure how the memory would be allocated since ex_ptr_vecA is initilized on the heap?

Answer (score 0):

Assignment

```
ex_ptr_vecA = ex_B->getfunction();
```

will cause a memory leak since the memory allocated by

```
new vector<A*>
```

will be inaccessible then. There will be no pointer to that memory, so you do not have any chance to free it...

I would suggest you to use shared smart pointers, then you can forget about freeing allocated memory and the order you should do it.

Comment: is that the case after I delete ClassB, as the destructors of classB de-allocate the memory?

Comment: why will the memory allocated by new vector<A*> be inaccessible?

Comment: Because the pointer on that memory will be overwritten by the other pointer returned by getfunction()...